# Separate a a data frame into its individual columns

Tags: r, dataframe

This seems like a fairly basic question, but I have been stuck on it for some time now. Would appreciate any help.

I have a data frame with a large number of columns, and want to split it into its individual columns, retaining the names. For instance, given the data frame `df` in the below code:

```
df = data.frame(a=runif(10),b=runif(10),c=runif(10))

df
#           a         b          c
# 1  0.2779563 0.1412121 0.81080549
# 2  0.9312947 0.2074081 0.23266019
# 3  0.2001917 0.8405399 0.79820815
# 4  0.3866977 0.4979865 0.57364238
# 5  0.2644731 0.2714174 0.24188040
# 6  0.1973641 0.3027505 0.01130486
# 7  0.7657212 0.1042998 0.69974274
# 8  0.6424601 0.4570072 0.91322978
# 9  0.3754743 0.5670109 0.03320163
# 10 0.5413522 0.2577974 0.48067775
```

I would like to have a function that would basically accomplish what the below lines of code do individually (assign the values of each column of `df` to an *eponymous* vector) -

```
a <- df$a; b <- df$b; c <- df$c

a
# [1] 0.2779563 0.9312947 0.2001917 0.3866977 0.2644731 0.1973641 0.7657212
# [8] 0.6424601 0.3754743 0.5413522
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's kind of hard to imagine a good use case for this but you could use

```
list2env(unclass(df), .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: As shown by @nrussel above, you don't even need to use `unclass`.

Comment: I cannot emphasize enough my agreement with "hard to imagine a good use case".

Comment: Thanks, it works. @joran: the only issue I have is that the number of columns is massive and I would like to have individual vectors to do certain operations on instead of referring to the "df$x" notations. A little bit of lethargy, I must admit. Any downsides that I should be aware of so as to not use it perhaps?..

Comment: @prateek1592, to avoid that typing it's often enough to use functions like `transform`, `within`, or `with` as in `with(df, sum(a/b) + c)`

Comment: @prateek1592 The major downside is that if there ends up being something repetitive that you want to do on a collection of those columns, it is _way_, _way_ better to have them all in a single data structure.

Comment: Sound advice. Shall try and incorporate into my prog. from now on. Thanks again, guys!